# NPM install error running Docker on CentOS

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm following this tutorial to dockerize a node.js app and it always fails at the 'npm install' part in the Dockerfile. Here is the link to the tutorial: http://docs.docker.com/examples/nodejs_web_app/

The error I'm getting is shown below:

```
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/src/package.json'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-43-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /src
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.6
npm ERR! path /src/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /src/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I've searched multiple sources and I'm not sure why npm can't find the 'package.json' file. I've also done the same setup except with an ubuntu 14.04 image and that doesn't work either, but it works if I manually go into the image and start the nodejs server myself.

If anybody with more experience with docker or npm could help out on this issue that'd be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Does /src/package.json exist? No extra characters in the name or anything?

Comment: Right above that docker will have printed out an image ID of the image it's running that command in.  `docker run {image_id} /bin/bash` then `ls` and see if package.json exists.

Comment: @vogonistic Yes my /src/package.json file does exist and it is spelt properly, have any idea why npm can't find the file?

Comment: @generalhenry So the "package.json" file isn't there and I tried to get the "/src" directory to copy over properly but for some reason when I place either: "ADD . /src" or "COPY . /src" in the Dockerfile, docker doesn't actually copy the folder over to the root directory in centos. I noticed something similar when I was setting this up with Ubuntu except on the Ubuntu server it was able to copy the files over but the "npm install" command would consistently fail despite the "package.json" file being present in the dirrectory. Any ideas?

Comment: I just did `git clone` of the repository, got a file, put it in a Dockerfile and `docker build --tag=nodejs .`went fine, image built successfully

Answer (score 4):

I was having this same problem, turns out the Docker tutorial is a bit ambiguous and makes it easy to screw up the directory tree if you don't understand the behavior of COPY.

I had this directory tree:

```
workdir/Dockerfile
workdir/src/package.json
workdir/src/index.js
```

The command `COPY . /src` results in the following tree in the Docker image:

```
/src/Dockerfile
/src/src/package.json
/src/src/index.js
```

So basically, put `package.json` and `index.js` in the same folder as your Dockerfile and it should work fine.

---

One other thing, when debugging a failed build like this, you can use the image ID to have a peek at the directory tree even if the container isn't running. For example, given the following `docker build` output:

```
Step 4: RUN cd /src; npm install
 ---> Running in 4bce6ad89dab
 ---> 3084f3523d93
ERROR! BAD THINGS! PANIC!
```

The image ID in this case is `3084f3523d93`, so you can run `docker run --rm 3084f3523d93 ls -lR /src` to inspect the /src directory and see what went wrong. Alternatively, use `/bin/bash` in place of `ls -lR /src` to get a shell and poke around.