# Docker compose bind failed: port is already allocated

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have been trying to get a socketio server moved over from EC2 to Docker.

I have been able to connect to the socket via a web (http) client, but connecting directly to the socket via iOS or Android seems to be impossible.

I read one of the issues can be the ports exposed are not actually published when using Docker. Since our mobile apps currently connect on port 8080 on our classic EC2 instance. I setup a docker-compose.yml file to try and open all ports and communication protocals, but I am two issues:

**1. I am not sure what the service should be called so I went with "src" (see DockerFile below). But wondering if it should be app since server file is app.js?**

**2. Getting "Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080 failed: port is already allocated".**

DockerFile

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN mkdir /src
ADD package.json /src

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install --yes curl
RUN curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo bash -
RUN apt-get install --yes nodejs
RUN apt-get install --yes build-essential

RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/node node /usr/bin/nodejs 10



RUN cd /src; npm install
RUN npm install --silent socket.io@0.9.14


WORKDIR /src




# Bundle app source
# Trouble with COPY http://stackoverflow.com/a/30405787/2926832
COPY . /src

ADD app.js /src/


EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["node", "/src/app.js"]
```

Docker-Compose.yml

```
src:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - ./:/src
  expose:
    - 8080
  ports:
    - "8080"
    - "8080:8080/udp"
    - "8080:8080/tcp"
    - "0.0.0.0:8080:8080"
    - "0.0.0.0:8080:8080/tcp"
    - "0.0.0.0:8080:8080/udp"
  environment:
    - NODE_ENV=development
    - PORT=8080
  command:
    sh -c 'npm i && node server.js'
    echo 'ready'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 2. Getting "Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080 failed: port is already allocated".

you have duplicated port allocations.

1. when not specifying a connection type, [the port defaults to `tcp`:](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports) meaning `"0.0.0.0:8080:8080"` and `"0.0.0.0:8080:8080/tcp"` both trying to bind to the same port and hence your error.
2. since [docker uses `0.0.0.0` for default binding](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/), same applies to `"8080:8080/tcp"` and `"0.0.0.0:8080:8080/tcp"` - you have no need in both of them.

therefore, you can shrink your `ports` section to:

```
   ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    - "8080:8080/udp"
```

---

> I am not sure what the service should be called

it is completely up to you. usually services are named after their content, or role in the network, such as `nginx_proxy` `laravel_backend` etc. so `node_app` sounds good to me, `app` is also ok in small networks, `src` doesnt appear to have any meaning but again - it is just some identifier for your service, without any additional effect.

Answer (score 7):

You are just running another container on the same port. You can view it by `docker ps` and stop it by `docker stop [CONTAINER ID]`.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to open docker.yml file and change your port address.....this happen for me because already that container was used by my company another member

example from 0.0.0.0:80==>0.0.0.0:8000
and also port from ports:- 80/80 to ports:- 8000:8000