# Bind for 0.0.0.0:6543 failed: port is already allocated (it's not)

Tags: windows, docker, netstat

I'm trying to start a docker project and get this error:

```
Bind for 0.0.0.0:6543 failed: port is already allocated
```

A `netstat -ano | findstr :6543` search returns nothing as does a `docker container ls`.

How do I free up that port?

Comment: This might not be relevant if the container doesn't show, but are you sure the docker project you're starting doesn't have duplicated port allocations? Netstat wouldn't show that, of course. Like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56285989/docker-compose-bind-failed-port-is-already-allocated

Comment: Does this show the same thing? https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html