# Why does my exposed Docker port not allow connections?

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a docker container on Fargate/CloudFormation. I can connect to the socket.io server on port 8080 via an http client, but cannot directly connect the tcp socket connection (our iOS and Android apps connect directly and they are failing because they do NOT use webviews or http; rather socket libraries).

If I test port 8080 it fails, but if I test port 80 it connects (see below)

```
 nc -vz produ-Publi-10SNDOZB9E1YC-1684595318.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com 8080
    nc: connectx to produ-Publi-10SNDOZB9E1YC-1684595318.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com port 8080 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
    nc: connectx to produ-Publi-10SNDOZB9E1YC-1684595318.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com port 8080 (tcp) failed: Connection refused


nc -vz produ-Publi-10SNDOZB9E1YC-1684595318.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com 80
    found 0 associations
    found 1 connections:
         1: flags=82<CONNECTED,PREFERRED>
        outif en0
        src 192.168.1.231 port 55691
        dst 52.32.233.92 port 80
        rank info not available
        TCP aux info available

    Connection to produ-Publi-10SNDOZB9E1YC-1684595318.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com port 80 [tcp/http] succeeded!
```

DockerFile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN mkdir /src
ADD package.json /src

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install --yes curl
RUN curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo bash -
RUN apt-get install --yes nodejs
RUN apt-get install --yes build-essential

RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/node node /usr/bin/nodejs 10



RUN cd /src; npm install
RUN npm install --silent socket.io@0.9.14


WORKDIR /src




# Bundle app source
# Trouble with COPY http://stackoverflow.com/a/30405787/2926832
COPY . /src

ADD app.js /src/


EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["node", "/src/app.js"]
```

Comment: There is nothing here that shows you are trying publish container port 8080 on host port 80. Port publishing only happens at *runtime* using the `--publish` (`-p`) option to `docker run` (or the equivalent configuration in `docker-compose`).

Comment: EXPOSE makes the service you're running available on the docker network, not outside it. So if you want to connect to it from outside the docker network, you need to publish/port forward your host port to map to 8080(in your case) while starting th container.

Comment: I have a docker file and I can use -p locally, but I cannot seem to find a way to use docker-compose while pushing to AWS.  I use aws cloudformation deploy --stack-name=productionfg --template-file=recipes/public-vpc.yml --capabilities=CAPABILITY_IAM