# How to resolve "FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR"?

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

I have successfully built docker image but when I try to login to the image, I am facing an issue. I am building an image with ubuntu as base with node-10.15.3, mongo-latest and redis-4.0.1.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo bash -
RUN apt-get install --yes nodejs
RUN apt-get install --yes build-essential

COPY . /src

RUN cd /src
RUN npm install -g npm
#RUN npm install

EXPOSE 8080

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y redis-server
EXPOSE 6379

RUN apt-get update
RUN 
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10 && 
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list && 
apt-get update && 
apt-get install -y mongodb-org && 
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

VOLUME ["/data/db"]

WORKDIR /data

EXPOSE 27017
EXPOSE 28017

ADD run.sh /run.sh
RUN chmod +x /run.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/redis-server"]
#CMD ["node", "index.js"]
CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

run.sh file:

```
nodaemon=true

command=node index.js

command=mongod
```

After successfully building this Dockerfile, when I try to login to the image, I get below output:
*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 3

> > > 'command=node index.js'
> > >       Bad directive or wrong number of arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way I think to remove `ENTRYPOINT` and write your run.sh script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /data
/usr/bin/redis-server &
mongod &
node index.js
```

since working on windows, here are the full example:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo bash -
RUN apt-get install --yes nodejs
RUN apt-get install --yes build-essential

COPY . /src

RUN cd /src
RUN npm install -g npm
#RUN npm install

EXPOSE 8080

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y redis-server
EXPOSE 6379

RUN apt-get update
RUN 
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10 && 
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list && 
apt-get update && 
apt-get install -y mongodb-org && 
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

VOLUME ["/data/db"]

WORKDIR /data

EXPOSE 27017
EXPOSE 28017

ADD run.sh /run.sh
RUN chmod +x /run.sh
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dos2unix && dos2unix /run.sh
CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

anyway that is a bad idea to start more than one service in a `container`

Comment: Thanks. Image is successfully built, but when I login to the image using docker run -it <image_id>, I get the below error:
standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "exec format error"

Comment: I get this error, when I login to my docker image:
standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"

Comment: I ran the command and getting the below error:
Step 21/22 : RUN apt-get install -y dos2unix && dos2unix run.sh
 ---> Running in f85ae66196d1
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package dos2unix
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y dos2unix && dos2unix run.sh' returned a non-zero code: 100

Comment: getting the below error:
_Selecting previously unselected package dos2unix.
(Reading database ... 20824 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dos2unix_6.0.4-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dos2unix (6.0.4-1) ...
Setting up dos2unix (6.0.4-1) ...
dos2unix: run.sh: No such file or directory
dos2unix: Skipping run.sh, not a regular file.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y dos2unix && dos2unix run.sh' returned a non-zero code: 2_

Comment: However, when I try logging in to the image, I get error as below:

_2019-06-27T14:23:28.152+0000 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2019-06-27T14:23:28.152+0000 [initandlisten] options: {}
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/data/index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:140:18)
    at node.js:1043:3_

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct working code:
Dockerfile:

```
# Pull base image.
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# Install Node.js
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install --yes nodejs
RUN apt-get install --yes build-essential

# Bundle angular app source
# Trouble with COPY http://stackoverflow.com/a/30405787/2926832
COPY . /src

# Install app dependencies
RUN cd /src
RUN npm install -g npm
#RUN npm install

# Binds to port 8080
EXPOSE 8080

# Installing redis server
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y redis-server
EXPOSE 6379

# Update the repository sources list
RUN apt-get update

# Install MongoDB.
RUN \
    apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10 && \
    echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y mongodb-org && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    cd / 

COPY index.js .

# Define mountable directories.
VOLUME ["/data/db"]

# Define working directory.
WORKDIR /data

# Define default command.
#CMD ["mongod"]

# Expose ports.
#   - 27017: process
#   - 28017: http
EXPOSE 27017
EXPOSE 28017

ADD run.sh /run.sh
RUN chmod +x /run.sh
#  Defines your runtime(define default command)
# These commands unlike RUN (they are carried out in the construction of the container) are run when the container
#ENTRYPOINT  ["/usr/bin/redis-server"]
#CMD ["node", "index.js"]
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dos2unix && dos2unix /run.sh
CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

code in run.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /data
/usr/bin/redis-server &
mongod &
node /index.js
```

code in index.js file:

```
console.log("helllllllooooo");
```